# How to hide the "hidden-but-not-really-hidden" parental controls icon on Windows 7 system tray

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, parental-controls

When Parental Controls are in effect, its icon gets displayed on the Windows 7 system tray.

I am trying to hide it by customizing the system tray, setting the Parental Controls to "only show notifications", but it still appears when I click the upright triangle icon in the system tray.

It seems that Windows 7 doesn't really intend to hide the icons, as it says:

"To view hidden icons at any time, click the arrow next to the notification area on the taskbar."

Question is, is there any way I can REALLY hide the Parental Controls icon? Haven't had any luck finding a solution on Google.

Comment: I don't believe hiding with these settings ever removes it from the list you see when you click the little up arrow.  Question though, on the screen where you choose to "only show notifications", at the lower left, can you check if parental controls are in the list if you click "Turn system icons on or off"?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't appear there unfortunately